# Python __init__.py so that package can be imported without 'from' keyword

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Lets say my package looks like this:

```
mydir/a/__init__.py
mydir/a/b.py
mydir/a/c.py
```

I have a package which has a few .py files in the same directory as `__init__.py`. Everything involving `__init__.py` I have tried so far results in imports needing to look like:

```
from a import b
from a import c
```

or

```
import a.b
import a.c
```

or by using the `__all__` variable in `__init__.py`:

```
from a import *
```

how can I setup the `__init__.py` so that I can import all packages within 'a' using:

```
import a
```